# using one google analytics code or script for multiple websites

Tags: google-analytics

I have 10 website domains and these domains are masked and forwarding to one website hosting place, in one website hosting place i handled with url what page i should open when specific domain is hit. now i want to put google analytics code in one place where one website is hosted. when i generate a code for website from google analytics, it generate one website code at a time. and i want to add it generically for all 10 websites,

Explaining the problem statement:
I have main domain named as abcd.com
and other domains are cde.com,efg.com,ghi.com etc
all cde.com,efg.com,ghi.com are redirecting with masking to abcd.com/id=123 or abcd.com/id=456 respectively.

my question is that if i create google analytics code for cde.com, and place it in abcd.com home page. it should work for all cde.com, efg.com,ghi.com etc sites. but unfortunately, i am unable to do.i have to create script seperately for all domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a single GA code across the site. All hits will be sent to the database associated with web property `UA-XXXXXX-Y`

GA will associate the hits with whatever hostname appears on the user's browser URL bar.

In GA, under property `UA-XXXXXX-Y` you can set up views for each domain:

- **All Web Site Data**: contains all hits across all domains
- **cde.com**: contains all hits for cde.com
- **fgh.com**: contains all hits for fgh.com
- ... etc ...

Comment: one more thing i want to clear, that should i create web property separately for each cde.com or fgh.com websites?

Comment: i mean when i will create object of GA, i will pas web properties that are already defined in google analytics for each website.

Comment: like this,
*******
ga('create', 'UA-111111-Y', {
  'cookieName': 'gaCookie',
  'cookieDomain': 'blog.example.co.uk',
  'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28 <br/>
});
********

ga('create', 'UA-22222-Y', {
  'cookieName': 'gaCookie2',
  'cookieDomain': 'blog.example.co.uk',
  'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28  
});
****************

ga('create', 'UA-33333-Y', {
  'cookieName': 'gaCookie3',
  'cookieDomain': 'blog.example.co.uk',
  'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28 
});